# Limit number of tablecells to be displayed

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, pagination

I am trying to do something like what FaceBook has done. Whereby it limits the number of cells it display. If the user would like to more items, he/she will scroll down the tableview and it will display more.

How do I go about doing so? Any tutorial out there? Sorry but I didn't know what to search for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is implemented in [STableViewController](https://github.com/shiki/STableViewController).

It basically checks the scroll position of the underlying UIScrollView of the UITableView to see whether it has reached the end of the page and then loads more content if it has. It also uses a custom tableFooterView to indicate that it is loading content.